# Handlebar context lost after passing handler

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am sure this is quite basic but I am unable to use ../model inside `{{#if_eq}}`. I even tried using ../../model and this points to a child of model._revs_info.

```
  {{#each model._revs_info}} 
        {{debug ../model}}
        {{#if_eq status compare="available"}} 
            {{debug ../model}}
            <a href="#list/{{model.id}}/{{rev}}">{{rev}}</a>
         {{/if_eq}}                                      
  {{/each}}
```

`{{#if_eq}}` has been copied from https://github.com/danharper/Handlebars-Helpers/blob/master/helpers.js

```
/**
 * If Equals
 * if_eq this compare=that
 */
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(context, options) {
    if (context == options.hash.compare)
        return options.fn(this);
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

`{{debug}}` has been copied from http://thinkvitamin.com/code/handlebars-js-part-3-tips-and-tricks/

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("debug", function(optionalValue) {
  console.log("Current Context");
  console.log("====================");
  console.log(this);

  if (optionalValue) {
    console.log("Value");
    console.log("====================");
    console.log(optionalValue);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Handlebars documentation on paths](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths),

> The ../ path segment references the parent template scope, not one
>   level up in the context. This is because block helpers can invoke a
>   block with any context, so the notion of "one level up" isn't
>   particularly meaningful except as a reference to the parent template
>   scope.

Each block helper defines a scope, so in if_eq your hierarchy looks like

1. base template,
2. each scope,
3. if_eq scope.

Point to the grand parent, `../../model` and you get the correct context.

And a Fiddle based on your code http://jsfiddle.net/aFGD6/ Another one with debug active, http://jsfiddle.net/aFGD6/1/